# FOREIGN KEY (`shiftid`, `groupid`, `sectionid`) REFERENCES `tbl_academic`(`id`, `id`, `id`) is not working in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_acc_payable` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_APAY_SGS` FOREIGN KEY (`shiftid`, `groupid`, `sectionid`) REFERENCES `tbl_academic`(`id`, `id`, `id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

why I cannot apply multiple columns references another table multiple column in MySQL database?

return Error Message:

> #1005 - Can't create table `fastpay`.`tbl_acc_payable` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: It's not 'another table multiple column', is it? And anyway, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite foreign key should reference a composite primary key. As you can't create a primary key on *triple ID* column, you should create 3 foreign keys, each of them referencing the same primary key (on the tbl_academic.id column).

Answer (score 0):

FK references used the whole expression value or its prefix. The value - not the column name.

You need to reference to the values in 3 different rows which cannot be provided by composite index. So create 3 separate foreign keys referred to the same index `tbl_academic(id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_acc_payable 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_APAY_SGS_1
  FOREIGN KEY (shiftid) 
  REFERENCES tbl_academic(id) 
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_APAY_SGS_2 
  FOREIGN KEY (groupid) 
  REFERENCES tbl_academic(id) 
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_APAY_SGS_3 
  FOREIGN KEY (sectionid) 
  REFERENCES tbl_academic(id) 
  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: yes I know but this option provides PHPMyAdmin application append multiple columns but is not work